# Spring Integration : REST to JMS integration giving timeout error

Tags: rest, spring-integration, spring-jms, spring-integration-dsl

Hi I am trying to implement the following flow using Spring Integration.
Expose REST service, manipulate the payload, write the changed payload to JMS and respond back to the REST service.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow httpInputFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundGateway(“/company”)
                     .requestMapping(r -> r
                             .methods(HttpMethod.POST))
                    .requestPayloadType(com.poc.model.Company.class))
            .transform(jsonToObjectTransformer())
            .channel(requestChannel())
            .get();
}

@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel=“requestChannel”, outputChannel=“responseChannel”)
ObjectToJsonTransformer jsonToObjectTransformer() {
    return new ObjectToJsonTransformer();
}
@Bean
public DirectChannel requestChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}
@Bean
public DirectChannel responseChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}
@Bean
IntegrationFlow outboundFlow() throws Exception {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(responseChannel()) .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory()).destination(“samplequeue”))
            .get();
}
```

The request payload is reaching the queue. However, the REST service timeout with no reply. I need the transformed payload to be put in the queue and also sent to the response for the rest service. I could not find any examples available.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `responseChannel` must be `publishSubscribe` and you should have one more `bridge` subscrbiber to let to send reply back to the HTTP inbound gateway. The `Jms.outboundAdapter()` in one-way component and doesn't produce any replies. That's how your flow stops and doesn't response back to the entry point.

Your use-case can be written like:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow httpInputFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundGateway("/company")
                    .requestMapping(r -> r
                            .methods(HttpMethod.POST))
                    .reqestPayloadType(com.poc.model.Company.class))
            .transform(jsonToObjectTransformer())
            .publishSubscribeChannel(subscribers ->
                    subscribers.subscribe(f -> f
                        .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory()).destination("samplequeue"))))
            .bridge(null)
            .get();
}
```

The `publishSubscribeChannel()` provides required channel.
`subscribers.subscribe()` add that `Jms.outboundAdapter()` as a first subscriber.
The `.bridge()` is added as a last (second in our case) subscriber to that `publishSubscribeChannel()`.

The idea behind `BridgeHandler` to send its reply to the `replyChannel` header which is populated by the `Http.inboundGateway()`.

Comment: can you advise how to pass the bridge handler in .bridge()?  The bridge method expects Consumer<GenericEndpointSpec<BridgeHandler>> as an argument. And the samples are in xml, not in java dsl.

Comment: Must be `.brdige(null)`. We have added `.bridge()` without arguments after moving Java DSL to Spring Integration Core in 5.0.